# How to send the current page URL to a specified email id through a form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a page with a link or button which when clicked it sends the current URL to a specified email id as a message.

I want that functionality using AngularJS.

Comment: Perhaps you can try creating a form, then have hidden input that holds $window.location and then set up the form ng-click to send it to email perhaps you can find such handler with little search.

Comment: how to send mail using ng-click

Comment: @Rai  I just want to send the webpage url to man email id in angular js .

Comment: You cannot send mail via any javascript library Shobha(be it angular or jquery, etc.). You need to use some server side scripting language like nodejs or php or the like..

Comment: how to use php for it.

Comment: if you aren't really aware of PHP, I feel it would be better if you used NodeJS, since it uses javascript and you wouldn't have to migrate to a whole new language, plus it's faster and better performing than PHP.

Comment: How to use NodeJS then.

Comment: You might have to go through some basics of NodeJS. Shouldn't take you more than 10 or 15 mins of your time. Once you're done, you can refer to some articles on the web or [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982330/10232790) below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
HTML code:

<button ng-click="sendMail()"></button>
Controller:

$scope.message = {} // contact info goes here

$scope.sendMail = function(){
  var mail = 'mailto:g2jakh@yopmail.com?subject=' + $scope.message.name +
               '&body=' + $scope.message.content;
  $window.open(mail);
}
```

Read more from here
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718036/How-to-Make-an-Email-Web-App-using-Angular

I assume you have api and you want to post it

```
$scope.sendMail = function() {
  $http.post('v1/mail.php')
    .then(function(success) {
        console.log("Success", success);    
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
});
}
```

Comment: I have to use form tag for it? Controller function I have to write in another page?

Comment: Yes sure please help me.

Comment: <form method="post" action="mail.php">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="url" id="ipdId" value="https://youstable.com/{{vm.state}}-review">
    <center><button style="background:#1e73be;color:white;padding:8px 25px;border-color:transparent" ng-click="sendMail()" type="submit">Report</button></center>
  </form>

Comment: @ShobhaPatwal updated code inside $http.post() you have to set route url. please ensure

Comment: No I don't have any API.

Comment: https://www.techieupgrader.in/2017/02/email-sending-with-angularjs-and-php.html

Check this if it doesn't help let me know

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly send mail from any Javascript library(AngularJS, Jquery, etc.). you need to use some sort of server side scripting language like NodeJS, PHP, etc.

I personally prefer the use of NodeJS because of its performance and ease of use for those who have worked on Angular.

NodeJS is a great choice for freelancers and open source projects, hence you could find a lot of tweaks applicable to many real life uses. And as per your current requirement, it offers a great range of packages, one of which is the [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/).

You can refer to [this](https://appdividend.com/2017/08/11/send-email-in-node-js/) guide for a start. It should also help you out with respect to your current problem.

Here is just a slight intro to what your node part should contain:

```
app.get('/send', function(req, res) {
  var mailOptions = {
    to: req.query.to,
    subject: req.query.subject,
    text: req.query.text
  }
  console.log(mailOptions);
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.end("sent");
    }
  });
});
```

In case you're wondering what your `HTML` should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Node.JS Email application</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    var from,to,subject,text;
    $("#send_email").click(function(){      
        to=$("#to").val();
        subject=$("#subject").val();
        text=$("#content").val();
        $("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){
        if(data=="sent")
        {
            $("#message").empty().html("Email is been sent at "+to+" . Please check inbox!");
        }

});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Mailer In Node.JS</h1>
        <input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail ID where you want to send" />
        <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Write Subject" />
        <textarea id="content" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Write what you want to send"></textarea>
        <button id="send_email">Send Email</button>
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**P.S.:** Remember this isn't a complete code, but is an overview. Refer to the links I have provided for better understanding.